# PHP Session not working, cannot bring value over the next page

Tags: php, html

need help about session, not sure whats going wrong.

Page 1

```
    <?php session_start()?>
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
        <body>
          <?php
            $_SESSION['name'] = 'John';
            Print_r ($_SESSION);
          ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Page 2

```
    <?php session_start()?>
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
        <body>
          <?php  
           Print_r ($_SESSION);
          ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Page 1 Result
Array ( [name] => John )

Page 2 Result
Array ( )

I did have session_start(); at both pages

Tried IE and Firefox but didnt work

Advices please and thanks :)

Comment: Post your code _with_ `session_start()` in place

Comment: Ensure you have no output (HTML code or any of echo, print_r, etc) before `session_start()`.

Comment: Are the two pages on the same subdomain?

Comment: try `<?php print_r($_COOKIE);?>`

Comment: How does the page flow from Page 1 to Page 2?

Comment: @bažmegakapa What do you meant by subdomain, sorry just started doing php recently.

Comment: i suppose this is mistyped?  <?php session_start()?> to     <?php session_start(); ?>

Comment: @user1436885 For example bazmegakapa.com and www.bazmegakapa.com (or even something.bazmegakapa.com). They are not the same.

Comment: @YouQi both pages have Array ( [BCSI-AC-8e905d6ebcb597fe] => 1ED4012A00000004uUrW0SGZ8RScBwfEhZJVJqBlK/lQAAAABAAAAN SEgAgHAAACAAAACXBAAA= ) . what does it means? enlighten me please

Comment: @bažmegakapa http://homes.soi.rp.edu.sg/102223/fypbilly/test1.php to http://homes.soi.rp.edu.sg/102223/fypbilly/test2.php

Answer (score 1):

As stated by lanzz, you need either to call `session_start()` in both pages or set the `session.auto_start` to 1 on yout `php.ini`.

**AFTER EDIT**

You seem to have some spaces before the php opening tag (`<?php`). It must be the first thing to be evaluated. If it isn't, it can't send the headers with the session data, and thus they do not work. It should emit a warning, so you probably have them disabled. To fix it, write the code as follows.

```
<?php session_start()?>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
    <body>
      <?php
        $_SESSION['name'] = 'John';
        Print_r ($_SESSION);
      ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

If they still don't work, you'll probably have the file as UTF-8 **With BOM**, you should disable the BOM. How to do it depends on the editor.

Comment: Sorry, but quoting from the question: `I did have session_start(); at both pages `.

Comment: Still, you can try with `session.auto_start` to check if it's something related with the file or if it has to do with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `session_start()` on top of all the page

Comment: I just edited and had put session_start() before <html> on body pages

Answer (score 0):

1. try `<?php print_r($_COOKIE);?>`. and make sure you have `PHPSESSID` cookie.
2. `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` and make sure `session.save_path` is writable by your apache user.

**UPDATE:**

it seems obvious your browser did not pass in the required cookies. Can you double confirm your phpinfo whether `session.name` is `PHPSESSID`?

To check whether the directory is writable, simply run a php file with script below:

```
<?php
    $fp = fopen('D:\xampp\tmp\test.txt', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, 'test');
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: both pages have Array ( [BCSI-AC-8e905d6ebcb597fe] => 1ED4012A00000004uUrW0SGZ8RScBwfEhZJVJqBlK/lQAAAABAAAAN SEgAgHAAACAAAACXBAAA= ) for print_r($_COOKIE);

Comment: Hi, my session.save_path is at D:\xampp\tmp. How do I know whether is it writable by my apache user. Sorry for the noob quesiton

Comment: Yes it is PHPSESSID, session.name PHPSESSID PHPSESSID. Is it because Im running not on a local host? Meaning like im using my school server. Because before using my school server, my session is working but now suddenly cant work. I had tried changing back to localhost and run but it also couldnt work.  About the script, I run but nothing came up, just a blank screen. Dang this problem hindering the process of my project. :/